# Node JS Live Reporting(Graphical) Modules

Tags: linux, web-services, node.js, load-balancing, forever

I have a production web service built with Node JS(HTTP Server) on a Linux box with a HAProxy Load Balancer and wanted some kind of graphical tool to do live reporting on the server.  I specially wanted to look at requests/min, request failures, etc.  Anything out there people would suggest.  I need something non-intrusive b/c I will be handling 20mil+ requests a day.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at cube (https://github.com/square/cube), graphite/carbon (http://graphite.wikidot.com/) or opentsdb for such data monitoring/display?

Comment: I have looked at graphite, but not cube.  I will check them out. thanks